# Не подключается сертификат Let's Encrypt к telegram

Tags: telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста, при использовании команды https://api.telegram.org/bot(token)/getWebhookInfo
получаю ответ {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"[https://домен/bot.php](https://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/bot.php)","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":40}}
В чем может быть проблема? Сертификат использую Let's Encrypt.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что здесь есть какая-то проблема? Если вы про has_custom_certificate, то он и должен быть false

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, вопрос закрыт) просто false как красная тряпка для быка))